# A Cryptic Riddle for Puzzlers

Tags: cipher, poetry

You asked your friend Joe, (whom you know to be avid about cryptography), who he would ask to dance with at Prom and you receive later inside your locker signed by Joe this:

Happy as a *L*ark in a meadow,

Kind as a anonymous donor,

as Sunny and the mids*u*mmer's day,

Reliable as the sun rise that *c*omes daily,

this is m*y* answer, Zack

-Joe

Hint 1

> You will have to do some cryptography.

Hint 2:

> The cipher used is a simple substitution.

Hint 3

> The cipher used is *not* a caesar cipher

Comment: Why is this being downvoted again? Is it because of the rot13(ureevat)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is

> Sophia

which you find by

> Taking the capital letters in the text ('HLKSRZ') and seing that as a Atbash ciphertext (i.e. $A\leftrightarrow Z$, $B\leftrightarrow Y$ $\dots$)

or

> Make it Sophia-Lucy or Lucy-Sophia if you want to consider the red herring :) (If you take the italic letters in the plaintext, you get 'LUCY')

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that

> there are four italicized letters which spell out "Lucy."

So, Joe wants to go to prom with

> Lucy!

It's fairly simple, and I don't see any substitution here, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucy_(Australopithecus) This one?

Comment: @WhatsUp - Not my thoughts, exactly... :)

Comment: Sorry, I set that up. That is not the correct answer. There is some encryption involved.

Comment: @Neo1009 is it useful though, or just a red herring?

Comment: @eru-cs rot13 Gung jnf n snyfr genvy.

Comment: Is it not okay to put rot13 snyfr genvyf??

Comment: @Neo1009 - It's fine, but _not_ if the "snyfr genvy" (as you say) is a ***valid answer!***

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath It is not the valid answer.

Comment: @Neo1009 - I'm not sure you understand. There should only be one clear, valid answer. My answer is valid as it is a common female name and that is what we are looking for in this puzzle.

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath I said in the hints that there is some encryption involved. The name LUCY was not encrypted.

Comment: @Neo1009 - Unfortunately, hints don't count as part of the "actual puzzle."

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath There, edited the question to clear things up.